# Как числа из массива перенести в строку?

Tags: c++

Как числа из массива перенести в строку?
Например массив `arr[5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, а строка пустая.

Answer (score 4):

Что именно вы хотите? просто собрать строковые представления элементов массива?

Так сойдет?

```
template<typename Container>
string to_string(const Container& n)
{
    return accumulate(begin(n),end(n),string(),
                      [](string r, int x) {
                          return r += to_string(x); } );

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> num = {12, 34, 56, 78};
    int arr[5] = {6,7,8,9,0};
    cout << to_string(num) << endl;
    cout << to_string(arr) << endl;
}
```